# \label does not work with custom textboxes

Tags: hyperref, tcolorbox, labels

I am using custom text boxes in a math document (amsart class) using tcolorbox. The essential code for the textbox is as follows.

```
\newtcbtheorem[use counter*=theorem]{theorembox}{Theorem}%
{
 ...
        },
    },
    #1,
}{th}
```

Whenever I generate an instance of this environment, the counter value is correct (e.g. box is titled "Theorem 2.3") which I'm assuming is because it's using the same counter as the other math environments like for definitions and propositions, but when I label an instance of the textbox with \label and then try to use the counter value in writing with \ref, the value comes out incorrect. It seems to always be the value 1 (in my actual document) and it simply won't display a value in a test file I made when trying to debug the issue.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

The test file looks like this.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[margin=1in ]{geometry} 
\usepackage{hyperref}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{xca}[theorem]{Exercise}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{nts}[theorem]{Note To Self} 
\newtheorem{question}[theorem]{Question}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}




% NOTE BOX
%================================
%\renewcommand{\begin{note}}{\begin{proof}}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins} % for attached boxed title to top left,  minipage boxed title, boxed title style, enhanced jigsaw, drop shadow,
\tcbuselibrary{theorems} % for the `\newtcbstheorem` macro
\tcbuselibrary{breakable} % for the breakable option
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur} % for the 'blur shadow' option in the underlay
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,shadows.blur}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tcbset{
    before={\par\vspace{0pt}},
    after={\par\vspace{0pt}},
    before upper={\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}\parindent=0pt},
    after upper={\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}\parindent=0pt}
}

\newtcbtheorem[use counter*=theorem]{theorembox}{Theorem}%
{
    enhanced jigsaw,
    colback=gray!20!white,%
    colframe=gray!80!black,
    size=small,
    boxrule=1pt,
    parskip = 12pt,
    title=\textbf{Theorem},
    halign title=flush center,
    coltitle=black,
    drop shadow=black!50!white,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    minipage boxed title=3cm,
    boxed title style={%
        colback=white,
        size=fbox,
        boxrule=1pt,
        boxsep=2pt,
        underlay={%
            \coordinate (dotA) at ($(interior.west) + (-0.5pt,0)$);
            \coordinate (dotB) at ($(interior.east) + (0.5pt,0)$);
            \begin{scope}
                \clip (interior.north west) rectangle ([xshift=3ex]interior.east);
                \filldraw [white, blur shadow={shadow opacity=60, shadow yshift=-.75ex}, rounded corners=2pt] (interior.north west) rectangle (interior.south east);
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[gray!80!black]
                \fill (dotA) circle (2pt);
                \fill (dotB) circle (2pt);
            \end{scope}
        },
    },
    #1,
}{th}







\begin{document}
    \begin{definition}\label{keyA}
        content...
    \end{definition}

    \begin{remark}\label{keyB}
        content...
    \end{remark}
    
    \begin{theorembox}{}{} \label{keyC}
        content...
    \end{theorembox}

    \ref{keyA} is the first environment, \ref{keyB} is the second environment, and \ref{keyC} is the custom textbox.


\end{document}
```

Comment: you must set the label in the optional argument: `\begin{theorembox}[label=keyC]`, and do not repeat `#1` in the options, that is done automatically.